# How to set a cookie in a server side componet NextJS 14

Tags: next.js, next.js13

So I have a ssr component and this fetches data depending on its params

```
export default async function MapPage({ params }: { params: MapParameters }) {
if (!isValidDate(params.checkIn.toString()) && !isValidDate(params.checkOut.toString()) && id <= 0) {
    return (
        <>
            Invalid date or id
        </>
    )
}
else {
    try {
        const mapData: MapListResponse = await getMapData(params).......
```

Inside I am making a call to my api in Django using axios which will give me the data and render the page accordingly. The issue is that I would like to set the csrf token that my backend sends in its cookies. My plan was to grab this from the response headers and set it as a next js cookie (no the backend does not set it as it goes through nextjs first I think). But, when I do this inside the component I get an error saying that this can only be done in server side actions or routes. Any ideas over how do this? I had a separate action file but I get the same error.